# Content Type field on NewForm.aspx

Tags: 2013, content-type, edit-form

I have a custom list and I am using content types to add items to the list. I am using OOTB forms for new and edit items. One field that I see on the EditForm.aspx is the one that I hope I get on the NewForm.aspx also and it is the **Content Type** field. It is shown in the following screenshot. Do you know how to add that field on the NewForm.aspx page also?

[EditForm.aspx](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=95f13ed)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a unique query string parameter on the newform url that tells Sharepoint what form to render. You can put a content type field on a custom html or aspx page, then use web services to submit the item otherwise, you can't get that on the newform.

If you go to the list and use the ribbon to create each content type, you can snatch the URLs and then use those in your presentation logic for the users.

Comment: So the straight answer is that it is not possible without creating custom form for each content type?  I don't undrstand how MSFT can overlook this feature. What's the point of the Content Type field on the EditForm.aspx and not on NewForm.aspx which is after the fact?

Comment: Correct. The point of it being on the edit form is so that it can be changed from one content type to another. Laura Rogers has documented many use cases of document lifecycle and workflow by simply changing the content type of document or list item from one to another. It doent make a lot of sense for me to click a link to create Content Type A, then be presented with a dropdown asking me what content type I want it to be after explicitly clicking a link for type A.

Comment: Well, it makes sense to me, because after clicking the generic **New Item** link right above the list view, I have the opportunity to select which content type I need to enter.

Comment: Right, you are clicking a link for an explicit content type in that scenario, like TPS report, so why should the form then have an option to specifiy a content type other than TPS report, that makes no sense.

Comment: My needs are different. It is a design issue MSFT should address. One should have an option for not to select a default content type. In such a case user should be presented with a content type dropdown box on a NewForm.aspx.

Comment: It has been this way since the 2003 version, possibly even the 2001 version. It is what it is, if you need that functionality, you need to roll it yourself.

Comment: Of course 2013 is not same as what it was in 2001. There is always room for improvement. Know the URL for SP features request? I googled but didn't find any.

Comment: @EricAlexander FYI, here are a few use cases for having a Content Type selection box in the NewForm (in each case, users need to be able to create items of more than 1 content type): 1: Need to be able to email a single link to users or place that single link on a "Quick Links" page, instead of separate links for each possible CT. 2: Have a requirement to hide the ribbon; users will have to use the "Add Item" link below the list to create items. 3: Users in the organization aren't familiar/comfortable with SP and won't use the ribbon, but a combo box in a form is a familiar element for them.

Comment: Ya sure, there might be a million use cases for it, the fact of the matter is the product group hasn't given it to us, and you have to roll your own functionality if you want to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you create your own URL to NewForm.aspx without parameters,
the ContentTypeId is by default present as a QueryString parameter.

So you can add some JavaScript to that single NewForm.aspx (edit in advanced mode) 
just before the table of the form, that matches by ContentTypeId and prints a header.

If you don't have SharePoint Designer add a ContentEditorWebPart to page.

```
    <script>
        JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
        var ctID=JSRequest.QueryString['ContentTypeId'];
        var titles={
            '0x0100223....010019ABEA5C55C59D4383F98D5A938894D8' : 'Expense',
            '0x0100223....02006C9B8D0CCE23024EA3A01C9A93FAFBB3' : 'Invoice',
        };
        var title = titles[ctID] || ctID;
        document.write( String.format('<h1 title="{1}">New 365CSI: {0}</h1>', title,ctID ));
    </script>

    <table class="ms-core-tableNoSpace" id="onetIDListForm">
```

#### Always get the correct ContentTypeId

**After** pageload the ContentType info is always present in:

```
WPQ2FormCtx.ItemContentTypeId
and
WPQ2FormCtx.ItemContentTypeName
```

But you better make sure you reference the correct WebPart (WPQ2 most of the time)