# How can I find the link to the new item form for multiple new items?

Tags: 2010, list, form, hyperlink, newform

I have multiple content types in one list, 3 to be exact.

This allows us to have 3 different forms for one list.

I would like to link text directly to the form for each of these items.

I know to use the `site/list/newform.aspx` however, this only brings up the default new item form.

How can I find the form link for the other two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ContentType ID is available in the link to the NewForm

So you need to create 3 links which include that ID

Also read:
[Content Type field on NewForm.aspx](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126704/content-type-field-on-newform-aspx/154870#154870)

*since you are asking for 3 links and not a switch on the NewForm itself,

I am not marking the question as a duplicate*