# Multiple content types in a list different, shared column but different default value

Tags: 2013, list, content-type, default-value

Is it possible to use shared list columns with default values and set different default values per content type?

I have two content types, one is the List default `item content type`.  The `Test Area content type` was created at the site level and added to the List, it was added to my list with only the Title field, I then added List columns to this content type.

I want to use shared `list columns` with different `default values` for each content type.

[image: Content types]

In List Settings>Content Types>Test Area content type - when I am editing the content type, if I modify a field and set a default value I find that the same default value then is also set in the `Item` content type.  This is not the behaviour I expected or desire.  I expected I could set a default column value per content type.

[image: List column default value]

For example in the `Test Area` content type I set the AREA column to have a default value of `Test Area`.  But when I create `Item content type` it also uses the same default value - not what I wanted.

Here are the two forms, side-by-side showing the default value circled in red:

[image: New forms, side-by-side]

### Research

Similar post [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/186045/add-default-value-to-the-site-column-inside-content-type-using-javascript-sharep) - although I want to configure default values for list columns, not site columns.

### Update - test success

[image: Default Values success]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with list columns I believe, you need to use site columns, Assign it to CT and then at library level in each CT you can modify the default values.

Comment: Thanks Marek!  That worked perfectly.  I created a new Site Column > Added to my Content Type > changed the default value to 20%.  To test it, I also created a new Site Content Type > added the new Site Column to the new Content Type > set default value to 10%.